# Injecting service into controller fails Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have this structure: SimpleController depending on SimpleService depending on APIService.

When Im trying to inject SimpleService into controller it fails and throw this error:

> vendor.js:27948 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
>       at vendor.js:14466
>       at assertArg (vendor.js:16278)
>       at assertArgFn (vendor.js:16288)
>       at Function.annotate [as $$annotate] (vendor.js:18318)
>       at injectionArgs (vendor.js:19024)
>       at Object.instantiate (vendor.js:19075)
>       at Object. (vendor.js:18918)
>       at Object.invoke (vendor.js:19063)
>       at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (vendor.js:18902)
>       at Object.invoke (vendor.js:19063)(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:27948(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:24623$digest @ vendor.js:31489$apply @ vendor.js:31735done @ vendor.js:25970completeRequest @ vendor.js:26176requestLoaded @ vendor.js:26109

It does not give me any sense, it is throwing error at this function which is totally unrelated to anything Im doing in my code:

```
 function consoleLog(type) {
  var console = $window.console || {},
      logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop,
      hasApply = false;

  // Note: reading logFn.apply throws an error in IE11 in IE8 document mode.
  // The reason behind this is that console.log has type "object" in IE8...
  try {
    hasApply = !!logFn.apply;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (hasApply) {
    return function() {
      var args = [];
      forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
        args.push(formatError(arg));
      });
      return logFn.apply(console, args);
    };
  }

  // we are IE which either doesn't have window.console => this is noop and we do nothing,
  // or we are IE where console.log doesn't have apply so we log at least first 2 args
  return function(arg1, arg2) {
    logFn(arg1, arg2 == null ? '' : arg2);
  };
}
```

My APIService:

```
export class APIService {
  constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
  }

  requestApi(url) {
  }
}
```

APIService module:

```
import angular from 'angular';

import APIService from './apiService.service';

export default angular.module('acme.services.api', [])
  .service('apiService', APIService)
  .name;
```

SimpleService:

```
export class SimpleService {
  constructor(apiService) {
    this.service = apiService;
  }
}
```

SimpleService module:

```
import angular from 'angular';

import apiService from 'services/api/apiService';

import { simpleService } from './simpleService.service';

export default angular.module('acme.services.simpleService', [apiService])
  .service('socialWallService', simpleService)
  .name;
```

SimpleController:

```
export class SimpleController {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor($scope, $element, $animate, $sce, $attrs, simpleService) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$element = $element;
    this.$animate = $animate;
    this.simpleService = simpleService;
  }
}
```

and SimpleController directive

```
import { SimpleController } from './simple.controller';

export const simpleDirective = () => ({
  restrict: 'E',
  bindToController: true,
  scope: true,
  controller: SimpleController,
  controllerAs: '$ctrl',
});
```

and SimpleController module

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngAnimate from 'angular-animate';
import simpleService from 'services/simple/simple';
import { simpleDirective } from './simple.directive';

export default angular.module('acme.organisms.simple', [ngAnimate, simpleService])
  .directive('simple', simpleDirective)
  .name;
```

Any ideas?

If i remove dependencies on SimpleService no error is occuring and project is working fine.

Comment: Try running without bundling your scripts together. Your error message might make more sense that way.